# Not receiving emails from edge server - 6 hours later and I still can't see why

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

6 hours ago I stopped receiving email from our edge server.  We can send email out and we can send email to each other just not receive from external domains.

I re-established the subscription and it sets up ok but when I run a test-edgesynchronization on the edge server, I get:

```
Test-EdgeSynchronization : The Active Directory site for Hub Transport server {
0} was not found on its configuration object.
At line:1 char:25
+ test-edgesynchronization <<<<
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (:) [Test-EdgeSynchronization], Local
ServerException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AD6DE1DA,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.EdgeSync.
TestEdgeSynchronization
```

Does anyone have any pointers/advice on where I should start with this error?  I haven't found anything on Google.

Am I chasing a red herring?  Is there something else I should be looking at to try and resolve my issue?

Comment: FYI - Start-EdgeSynchronization seems to run fine with no errors

Comment: I'm a Linux guy, so I don't know much other than some important questions to ask.  Is DNS correct to the host still on the outside?  Is there a new firewall rule blocking things?  Also the error message does lead me to wonder if something was changed with AD or DNS, or if your server has no access to either now.

Comment: http://mxtoolbox.com/ Verify your dns is correct and that mail can get to your server from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't do too much with Edge servers, but giving a quick read of the [Test-EdgeSynchronization documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996925%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), this seems to stand out. It seems that the `Test-EdgeSynchronization` cmdlet should be run on your Hub Transport Server inside the firewall, and not your Edge Transport Server.

> To run the **Test-EdgeSynchronization** cmdlet, you must log on to a
>   computer that has the Hub Transport server role installed and that is
>   located in the Active Directory site to which the Edge Transport
>   server is subscribed. The account you use must be delegated the
>   following:
>
> - Exchange Organization Administrator role

I'd be checking you actually have inbound mail connectivity at all if I were you. On a computer not connected to your internal network or DMZ, try sending an email using telnet to your domain and see if you get some sort of useful error message. Also, check the queues on the Edge Transport server to see if they're filling up and have errors, or if they're totally empty.

Have you been fiddling around with DNS entries recently, or more specifically your MX records? Verify these point to where you expect them to (presumably your Edge Transport Server) and if they're being sent somewhere else before your Edge Transport Server (a firewall for instance) make sure the intermediary hops are all up and healthy.